# Cannot createdb in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql

I'm trying to start a Ruby on Rails app with PostgreSQL as the database because once this site is finished I'll be promoting it to another blog that has 259K followers and I just want to anticipate if the user base for my new website gets big.

Anyway I followed this tutorial: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan at first. But when I made my app with PostgreSQL the database would fail to create.

So I stepped back, tried uninstalling and reinstalling postgres, I updated my homebrew, and now I'm following this new tutorial: 
https://www.codefellows.org/blog/three-battle-tested-ways-to-install-postgresql#macosx

I'm at the step: Create a Default db Based on Your Username.

I run the command and get this:

```
Mayas-MacBook-Air:~ mayaah$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
Mayas-MacBook-Air:~ mayaah$ createdb `whoami`
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I don't know what to do from here. I've googled this problem extensively and couldn't find an answer. The only possible problem I can think of is my Mac has very little space left, as I saw something about "shared space" which I don't really understand.

Any insight into this, especially with specific step-by-step command line instructions would be super helpful. Thanks!

Edit:
Now I found this tutorial: http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/21/install-postgresql-on-mac-os-x-via-brew/

Tried to run

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Got this:

```
LOG:  skipping missing configuration file    "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf"
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.5.
```

I don't know what to do from here either.

Comment: It seems Postgres isn't running. Did you finish all previous steps? Try running `ps aux | grep postgres` and see if there's something.

Comment: I ran that and got: `mayaah          1302   0.0  0.0  2423376    296 s000  R+    9:55PM   0:00.00 grep postgres` I don't know how to interpret this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, you installed PostgreSQL version 9.3, then you uninstalled it and installed version 9.4. But some old files stayed there and PostgreSQL 9.4 is not compatible with them. If you don't need any data of 9.3 version then you can remove them and initialize new settings for 9.4 version:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

Comment: I did that. But now I get: `Mayas-MacBook-Air:~ mayaah$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
LOG:  could not translate host name "localhost", service "5432" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets`

Comment: And when I check: `Mayas-MacBook-Air:~ mayaah$ cat /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
192.168.1.2 server.domain
127.0.0.1 localhost.domain
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost.domain` it looks fine to me. I just keep running into more and more problems. Thank you though!!

Comment: But there's no `localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` file. Edit `127.0.0.1 localhost.domain` likes so: `127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.domain`

Comment: Wow! I think that did it. I saw this fix on another stackoverflow thread but dismissed it, thinking mine was already correct. Shouldn't be so confident next time haha. Thank you so much! I think my rails app is up and running correctly (for now)!